# Why should we load keystore variables from key.properties instead of env variables?

Tags: flutter, github-actions, apk, keystore, keytool

To build and release a Flutter app, it's [recommended](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app) that the keystore properties be stored in a file called `key.properties`:

```ini
storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step>
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=<location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/upload-keystore.jks>
```

and then in the `build.gradle` file, the values are loaded from that file:

```
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

Why don't we simply load the keystore properties from the system env variables? Like this:

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias System.getenv("keyAlias")
           keyPassword System.getenv("keyPassword")
           ...
       }
   }
```

This way, we will be also able to load those values from GitHub secrets when building the apk file in GitHub Actions. So what's the point or benefit of having a `key.properties` file?

Comment: Regarding your question "**what's the point or benefit of having a `key.properties` file?**", seems like it'll get more appropriate answers by [creating an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose) on the repo. And, regarding GHA, something like this `keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias'] ? keystoreProperties['keyAlias'] : System.getenv('keyAlias')` would support both.